# Is there any property or low-complexity algorithms to calculate matrix inverse where its inverse matrix is digonal dominant?

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Given a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times{} n}$ whose inverse $A^{-1}$ is [diagonally dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix):

1. Is there any property for the matrix $A$?
2. Are there lower-complexity (perhaps some approximation algorithms) algorithms to calculate $A^{-1}$ of this kind of matrices?

Comment: If the matrix is PSD and invertible, then it is positive definite. And so is its inverse.

Comment: The [Jacobi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) method.

Comment: The diagonally dominant matrix is its inverse. The matrix itself is not necessarily diagonal dominant.

Comment: This is a very unusual setup. You are much more likely to get answers if you explain the background for this question. If it is just a random question, then I cannot afford to spend time on it. The answer to question 2 is almost certainly no, unless you make additional assumptions which can be used to accelerate the computation of matrix vector products.

Comment: Thanks! The formulation of matrix $A$ is $I_{n}+K^{T}K$, where K is a m*n sized matrix. The value of the matrix $K$ is related to my application. What I have observed from lots of these data is that the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ is strongly diagonally dominant.

Comment: It is relevant to know if m is much smaller than n or not. It is very likely that your application has crucial properties that can help. If you add a name tag then the recipient gets a notification. I came here only during a daily sweep.

Comment: @CarlChristian In my application, m is larger than n. Typically, n is 10 and m is 70~140. Therefore, the size of A is 10*10. Though calculating only one matrix does not require much time, I have to calculate lots of these matrices in my application.

Comment: The dimension of the matrices suggests to me that nothing will beat an explicit computation and factorization of the matrix A. Why: you need to load/compute the entries of the matrix K anyway and storing a 10 by 140 matrix in double precision requires 11200 bytes, much less than the 32kb of many L1 caches. If you can define many matrices at the *same* time, then batched BLAS is an option you might want to explore.